# access application port : express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to build a simple chat application with node.js using Express.My node version is `v0.12.7` and express version is `4.13.1`. 
I need to access the port the application is listening to but I am not getting how to do that even after lot of research over google.

My code in index.js is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
 });

 io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('a user connected');
 });

  console.log(app.get('port')); // not working

 http.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.info('Server listening on port :');
 });
 module.exports = router;
```

Please suggest If this can be done and how. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the port, you're going to have to set it first like this

```
var app = require('express')();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
...
```